# Sequelize js not working as expected with Having and Group by

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, orm, sequelize.js

is there something wrong with my ORM query? I am trying to use sequelize `group` and `having` in order to filter Reservation dates that have more than 30 records:

```
SELECT "reservations"."reservationDate" FROM reservations, orders
WHERE "reservations"."orderId" = "orders"."orderId"
AND Orders.confirmed = true
GROUP BY "reservationDate"
HAVING COUNT("reservationDate") >= 30;
```

```
    db.Reservations.findAll({
      attributes: ['reservationDate'],
      where: {
        reservationDate: {
          [Sequelize.Op.between]: [fistMonthDay, lastMonthDay],
        },
      },
      include: [{
        model: db.Orders,
        attributes: [],
        where: { confirmed: true }
      }],
      group: ['reservationDate'],
      having: {
        [Sequelize.fn("COUNT", Sequelize.col("reservationId"))]: {
          [Sequelize.Op.gte]: 30,
        }
      }

    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy workaround:

```
having: Sequelize.literal(`count("reservation"."reservationId") >= 30`)
```